# BeautifulSoup returns None on an Amazon ID element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the price of an Amazon product by using the BeautifulSoup library but when I run the code, it returns None although the ID exists.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Silicone-Heat-Resistant-Spatulas-Non-stick-Stainless/dp/B01MR507HZ'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")
print(price)
```

I expect the output to be `$6.99`, but the actual output is `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the parser to `lxml` BeautifulSoup finds your tag:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Silicone-Heat-Resistant-Spatulas-Non-stick-Stainless/dp/B01MR507HZ'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")
print(price)
price_float = float(price.text.replace('$', ''))
print(price_float)
```

Prints:

```
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString" id="priceblock_ourprice">$6.99</span>
6.99
```

EDIT: In problems like these is often useful run `diagnose()` ([doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#diagnose))

Comment: When I run this code in the terminal, this is what it says:

`bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?`

What do I need to do to get your result?

Comment: @Anatol you need to install `lxml` package https://pypi.org/project/lxml/ I'm on version `lxml==4.3.3`

Comment: Thank you! And how can I easily extract the price as a float?

Comment: I am not sure what I need to use to extract the price itself. I would really appreciate if you could give me a suggestion 

Comment: @Anatol You basically run `float()` on the scrapped text, see the last 2 lines of my script.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! 

I have another question. How can I get the number of reviews a product has?

The id would be `acrCustomerReviewText`. 
And here is the span: `<span class="a-size-base" id="acrCustomerReviewText">1000 customer reviews</span>`

How can you get the int of the number of reviews the product has?

Comment: @Anatol Feel free to open new question here on StackOverflow. This comment section isn't place for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`import requests` 
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`
`URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Silicone-Heat-Resistant-Spatulas-Non-stick-Stainless/dp/B01MR507HZ'` 
`headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}` 
`page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)` 
`soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")` 
`price = soup.find('span', 'a-offscreen').get_text()`

When I try this I got only the price '$7.99 '